# Toggle Bolts in Concrete Ceiling

Tags: concrete, ceiling

I want to hang a baby bed in our bedroom (less than 20kg /44lbs).

I drilled a hole into the concrete ceiling.. which i was expecting to be quite thick, but its actually only about 4cm (1 9/16") depth!

I'm guessing it's made of stuff like in the pics below (as when i view this slab from the balcony it's very thick)
[image]

Originally i was thinking of using expansion bolts... but from reading data sheets it seems like i need a hole deeper than 4cm (1 9/16")

So thinking instead of using toggle bolts.

The questions are:

- Is 4cm (1 9/16" concrete) ok to be drilling and hanging 20kgs (45lbs)
  ?
- Any issues with using Toggle bolts to handle that weight?
- i read the data sheet from PowerFasteners (see snapshot below) and it seems to be totally fine Any issues with drilling two holes close to each other as a backup?

PowerFasteners Toggle Bolt Data sheet:
Allowable Load tension values look fine... 
[image]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would not put my faith in a regular toggle bolt. The small bend pin that acts as a hinge for the wing to pivot on and are critical for its integrity seem weak at best. I would rely on it for shear strength rather than tension.

[image: toggle 1]

Here is what I would use instead...

[image: toggle2]